# How to install gcc onto a RedHat Enterprise 5 virtual machine?

Tags: linux, gcc, tcl, rsync, redhat

I am trying to install gcc onto a linux RedHat Enterprise 5 virtual machine, and I have tried using a tar.gz package and also a rpm, and both methods give errors. The tar.gz says there is no c compiler found, and the rpm has dependencies that it can not find. Yum is available on this machine, however, there are no repositories found and I am still unsure of how to install the necessary repositories to get gcc installed. The end goal for installing gcc is to be able to install rsync, tcl, and the expect package for shell scripts. Any advice?

Comment: What happens when you run `yum list`?

Comment: RHEL by default has repo's enabled. but you can't use them unless you have a subscription.

what does yum repolist say?

Comment: yum list returns a lot of different .x86_64 installed items, but nothing that matches gcc. yum repolist gives: "repolist: 0"

Comment: @user2701571 You don't seem to be registered on the redhat network. You need to have a redhat subscription to installed software from the repositories... do you?

Comment: I'm not sure, however I am able to run a yum search for gcc and it returns a few results, would anyone know how to install any of these? `code# yum search gcc
================================= Matched: gcc =================================
libgcc.i386 : GCC version 4.1 shared support library
libgcc.x86_64 : GCC version 4.1 shared support library
libstdc++.i386 : GNU Standard C++ Library
libstdc++.x86_64 : GNU Standard C++ Library
libtermcap.i386 : A basic system library for accessing the termcap database.
libtermcap.x86_64 : A basic system library for accessing the termcap database.`

Answer (score 2):

Your .tar.gz probably didn't work because it was the raw source code for GCC. The source for the compiler requires a compiler to build it — the classic chicken & egg problem. To get around this, you'd need to get a precompiled compiler for your system's architecture. GCC is not offered in a precompiled form by the FSF, as far as I know. If you're ever interested in actually trying to build a Linux system from the ground up like that, you might find [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) interesting.

You'll probably not even need GCC to get `rsync`, `tcl`, etc. There are almost certainly pre-built packages available from yum repos for those tools. As @PeteyT said, RHEL uses a subscription to allow you to access packages using yum. You can learn more from the [Red Hat Subscription Management Guide](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Subscription_Management/1.0/html/Subscription_Management_Guide/index.html).

If you don't have a Red Hat subscription, you might be interested in [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS), [Scientific Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_Linux) and [Fedora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29). As I understand it, CentOS and Scientific Linux are meant to be almost identical to RHEL. On the other hand, Fedora is a separate project owned by Red Hat (according to Wikipedia) which is an OS in its own right, and sometimes serves as a feeder to Red Hat products.

Once you have repos available, either via subscription or switching OSs, you should be able to simply run `yum install rsync tcl expect` to install `rsync`, `tcl`, and `expect`.

You might look at [yum's docs](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumCommands) for more about the various commands you can use with `yum`, and [Red Hat's docs](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/part-Package_Management.html) for more on package management in RHEL.

Comment: CentOS is particularly intended to be RHEL without the subscription malarkey. Scientific Linux is a little bit different (in particular, it supports additional packages relevant to particular types of scientific research, notably but not exclusively high-energy physics). Fedora's more like a fork.